# Explorer.exe keeps crashing from StackHash

Tags: windows-10, crash, troubleshooting, windows-error-reporting

This happens every x amount of minutes on my computer and I have no idea what is causing it. I went into problem details to get the full explanation and still can't figure out why it's crashing randomly. If someone can help me or tell me why it is crashing that would be great. Thank you.

[image: crash proof]

Comment: When a program is corrupted in memory and Windows cannot tell where the code crashed then it does a stackhash of the stack to help in identifying similar problems. A stack is where parameters, local variables,  and the return memory address is stored.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and untick all NON Windows explorer extensions. In Options menu - Filter Options Hide Windows Entries then untick all that's left on Explorer tab. Does that fix it? If so reenable one by one. Run it as a limited user first and if that doesn't help run it as admin.

Comment: @Mark Nope that did not fix it and keeps crashing.

Comment: See if it goes away in _Safe Mode with Network_ (if you want to use the internet while testing).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that and the standard initial repairs (DISM and SFC) did not sort out this problem.  The error log is a log of what happened, and not the cause of the crash.

Try first a new, test Windows Profile. Log in to the new profile and test.

If you get the same issue in a different user profile, then do a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button), and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Failing the above, back up and do a Repair with Keep Nothing to do a new install.

Comment: I created a new profile and logged in and it still does it. So I am going to create an ISO with windows10 to repair the computer and see if that fixes it.

Comment: That means you need to do a Repair Install - Profile is OK

Comment: I did what you said and I repaired my computer from windows 10 setup. Strangely that did not fix the problem and it continues to happen. I used DebugDiag to see what is causing the crashes and it says [this](https://i.imgur.com/yNuRpkS.png)

Comment: At this point, you should back up all data, start the Repair again and Keep Nothing.  This is mostly a fresh install. I edited my answer above.